# Counting Archived Tasks in a Flow

Tags: soql, visual-workflow

I have a flow that counts certain tasks based on their subject line. I am assuming that when the tasks are archived the flow will no longer count them via a fast lookup. Does anyone know of a workaround or do I need to look at using a SOQL query to count all rows?

Comment: My guess is a soql querry with ALL ROWS. You should be able to use invocable method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Soql querry with all rows is your only option. There is an idea [Enable ALL ROWS Clause for Flow Lookups](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DntTAAS) you could upvote in the meawhile.

[Process Builder or Flow Record Update does not update Archived Activities](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000230783&language=en_US&type=1)

You can leverage the flow and invocable combination which enables you to call an apex method or try using triggers if you are calculating based on record changes.